# Getting a user IP in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the IP for a request in an MVC app.

Here's the code I have

```
 string srUserIp = "";

 srUserIp = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();

 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(srUserIp))
 {
   srUserIp = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
 }
```

This is in a method in a controller. This is throwing 'Object reference not set to an instance' error when the first line line of Request.ServerVariables is hit.

How to get the HttpContext object in a controller method so that I can get the requested user's IP and not the server's IP where the app is hosted?

Regards.

Comment: Before you check whether `ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` has returned something useful or `null`, you're calling `ToString()` on it. There really is no need - it returns `string`s anyway.

Comment: do not rely on these variables. They can be easily fooled as they can be sent maliciously by clients.

Answer (score 2):

If the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` server variable is null then doing a .ToString() on it will give an object reference not set.

```
srUserIp = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(srUserIp))
{
    srUserIp = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

As pointed out in one of the comments servervariables returns a string so no need to do a `.ToString()` at all